# Not updating profile picture in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is a bit of repetition on a previous question I asked. However, I believe I made substantial enough changes to the code to warrant asking a new question as I am getting a new error message.

This is my code in views.py(teachers.py):

```
# edit mentor profile
def edit_user(request):
    user = request.user
    # form = MentorProfileForm(instance=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        mentorform = MentorProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid() and mentorform.is_valid():
            form.save()
            mentorform.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s' % (reverse('profile')))
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        mentorform = MentorProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
    return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-profile.html', {'form': form,
                                                                              'mentor_form': mentorform})
```

forms.py

```
#basic form
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email')

# edit mentor profile
class MentorProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mentor
        fields = ('photo',)
```

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
...
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='media')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Profile of user {}".format(self.user.username)

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_or_update(sender, instance,created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        post_save.connect(create_or_update, sender=User)
```

the html form:

```
<form id="edit-mentor-profile" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="photo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Avatar</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="media v-middle">
                            <div class="media-left">
                              <div class="icon-block width-100 bg-grey-100">
                                  <img id="image" style="width:99%;height:99%;">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <input type="file" id="files" class="btn btn-white btn-sm paper-shadow relative" data-z="0.5" data-hover-z="1" data-animated/>
...
```

and this is where the image should appear

```
<img src="{{ mentorform.photo}}" alt="people" class="img-circle width-80" />
```

urls.py:

```
path('teachers/', include(([
    path('', teachers.QuizListView.as_view(), name='app-instructor-dashboard'),
    path('logout', teachers.logout_request, name="logout"),
    path('edit_user', teachers.edit_user, name='edit_user'),
], 'classroom'), namespace='teachers'))
...
#user profile image
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is where I added media url in settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
...
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Note I have edited the Httpredirect to redirect to edit user but still cannot update the profile picture

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('%s' % (reverse('teachers:edit_user')))
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to make some changes to urls.py - maybe my media files aren't being served if I don't check for debug however this hasn't changed anything still not updating the user's profile picture.

I also noticed when I run inspect where the image should appear on the web page I get this

```
<img src=(unknown) alt="people" class="img-circle width-80">
```

I noticed that I hadn't created the media folder so I manually created the folder, still not however updating my profile picture. Maybe the problem is with I am calling the picture in html?

Comment: can you provide your urls.py code ?

Comment: @LinhNguyen i had added urls.py

Comment: i do not see any url with `name='profile'` in your urls.py. in order to use reverse() you need to declare the url name inside of it

Comment: @LinhNguyen even if I use say edit_user I get the error message no reverse match. Besides this, if I remove the line completely everything else is updated except for the profile image

Comment: when you use name you don't use the url you use the value in `name` so it's `reverse('edit_user') ` don't need the teacher part

Comment: @LinhNguyen that returns an error message the line I added to the question actually redirects to the correct path. The problem however is the profile picture is still not being updated yet everything else is

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your models.py:

```
def mentor_photos(instance, filename):
    return 'mentor/photos/%s' % filename

class Mentor(models.Model):
    ...
    models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=mentor_photos)  # <-- Note the upload_to change
```

Comment: same error 'Reverse for 'edit_user' not found. 'edit_user' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
'. Besides this, even if I remove the line completely the image is not updated, yet everything else is. The problem lies with updating the profile picture

Comment: but isn't the file being uploaded to mentorform not form

Comment: @Emm Again changed the answer.

Comment: @Emm Question: Why do you try to find to image with <img src="{{ mentorform.avatar}}" ... as the model field name is "photo"?

Comment: yeah, noticed that some time ago, changed it though, will update. Still getting the same issue though

Comment: @Emm Is your models.py complete? Do each class have a save method?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Example: 
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Mentor, self).save(*args, **kwargs). This is called when you do the mentorform.save() in your views

Comment: Thanks, just tried adding that- still not updating, I don't think the media directory is being created

Comment: Can you post your templates = [] in your settings.py file and try change the MEDIA_ROOT to os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Comment: that's what I currently have in settings.py. posting what I have in templates now

Comment: I think there is also a problem with your urls.py setup. You are trying to add + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) to you urlpatterns if debug is true. Why only when debug is true? And what about the urlpatterns? Where is this variable initialised?

Comment: I tried removing if DEBUG, I added that under update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205682/discussion-between-w-white-and-emm).

Answer (score 0):

you have a name space of teachers in your url settings, so when you call url add the name space too.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('%s' % (reverse('teachers:profile')))
```

Comment: Please check question, added an update- already tried this. It works, but the problem is my profile picture is not being updated when I save

Comment: have you added media url in settings and url patterns?

Comment: updated the question with what i have on settings and urls.py